# Unable to send email using Postfix - Connection Refused

Tags: email, centos, postfix

I've set up Postfix on my server along with Squirrel Mail. However, every time I go to send an email to my Gmail account from the server the email never arrives. I get no bounce back emails, I get no emails in Junk. Nothing.

I've checked my maillog and I have found the following line:

```
Mar 16 07:55:23 setanta postfix/smtp[17339]: 64F235F83: to=<myemailaddress@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.07, delays=0.07/0.01/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to
127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)
```

In the `/etc/postfix/main.cf` I have changed the following:

```
inet_interfaces = all
inet_interfaces = $myhostname
inet_interfaces = $myhostname, localhost
inet_interfaces = all
```

I have removed `#` from each one of these options one at a time, restarted Postfix each time, but I still get the `Connection Refused` error. I don't know if it makes any difference, but when I go to send emails to this server the emails are never delivered either. But I get no bounce back emails either.

Comment: Some ISPs block port 25 for customers to prevent spamming and require you to use an smtp-relay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused by the amavisd service not being started. Once it was started it worked fine.